# Android ListView with XML Files?

Tags: android, xml, listview

I have several `*.xml` files, and I need to parse this data and display it as a list. Can anyone point me in the right direction of how to solve this problem? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: so what is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

If your question is about XML parsers available on Android, you can use both a DOM parser or a SAX parser, available in the package javax.xml.parsers.

Comment: i can able to get the data by using saxparser and displayed it in the text view but i can't able to display that in the listview...can u pls help me out?

Comment: Sorry, I missed this.  You'll need to create a ListAdapter of some sort in order to display your data.  Depending on how complex your data is, there are several choices.  If it's a fairly straightforward mapping of data to your desired view, a SimpleAdapter might work:  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html